# Match specific string from the first 3 characters and specific string anywhere from the 4th characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

**Problem**
I want to capture the string if the first 3 char is `YZA`, `YZB`, and `YZB` and another string is `NUM12345` located anywhere after the first 3 chars.

**Regex** I am using that does not match the strings with the format described above:

```
^YZ[ABC]\sNUM12345
```

Here are the sample lines:

```
YZC/GH/A1/M,KNUM12345
YZB/M,SD-GG,K*NUM12345/A2
YZA/A1/M,SD-GG,KNUM12345/A2
YZB/M,SD-GG,K*NUM12345/A2/AA
YZA/A1/M,SD-GG,KNUM12345/A2/A2A
YZW/GH/A1/M,KNUM12345
YZR/M,SD-GG,K*NUM12345/A2
YZS/A1/M,SD-GG,KNUM12345/A2
YZT/M,SD-GG,K*NUM12345/A2/AA
YZJ/A1/M,SD-GG,KNUM12345/A2/A2A
```

The lines I am trying to match:

```
YZC/GH/A1/M,KNUM12345
YZB/M,SD-GG,K*NUM12345/A2
YZA/A1/M,SD-GG,KNUM12345/A2
YZB/M,SD-GG,K*NUM12345/A2/AA
YZA/A1/M,SD-GG,KNUM12345/A2/A2A
```

Anyone can help correct the pattern below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^YZ[ABC].*NUM12345.*
```

See the regex demo:

[image]

If you want to remove all lines other than the ones that match the above pattern, you can use

```
^(?!YZ[ABC].*NUM12345).*\R*
```

See the regex demo:

[image]

*Details*:

- `^YZ[ABC].*NUM12345.*` - start of string, `YZ`, `A` / `B` or `C`, then any zero or more chars (other than line break chars) as many as possible, `NUM12345` and then any zero or more chars (other than line break chars) as many as possible.
- `^(?!YZ[ABC].*NUM12345).*\R*` - start of string, then a negative  lookahead that fails the match if the above pattern is matched, and then any zero or more chars (other than line break chars) as many as possible and then any zero or more line break sequences.